# Not receiving NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification from NotificationCenter using C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I'm trying to listen for macOS sleep/wake events using C# .Net Core in Visual Studio for Mac. After searching the forum and various documentation I've written some code that should apparently receive these notifications. Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

using CFNotificationCenterRef = System.IntPtr;

namespace NativeMac
{
// I've noticed that some people are using this attribute to decorate their callback method.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute(Type delegateType)
    {
        DelegateType = delegateType;
    }

    public Type DelegateType { get; }
}

// Delegate definition for a notification center callback.
delegate void CFNotificationCallback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, IntPtr observer, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj, IntPtr userInfo);

// Required enum for the call to CFNotificationCenterAddObserver.
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1008:Enums should have zero value", Justification = "There is no zero value specified for NotificationSuspensionBehavior.")]
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1028:Enum Storage should be Int32", Justification = "Required to be long to work with IntPtr.")]
public enum CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior : long
{
    Drop = 1,
    Coalesce = 2,
    Hold = 3,
    DeliverImmediately = 4
}

/// <summary>
/// The intention is for this class to allow us to register for the Mac's native sleep and wake events.
/// </summary>
public static class MacPowerMode
{
    private enum CFStringEncoding : uint
    {
        UTF16 = 0x0100,
        UTF16BE = 0x10000100,
        UTF16LE = 0x14000100,
        ASCII = 0x0600
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Native methods we can call on the Mac.
    /// </summary>
    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        private const string FoundationFramework = "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation";
        private const string AppKitFramework = "/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit";

        [DllImport(AppKitFramework, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Globalization", "CA2101:Specify marshaling for P/Invoke string arguments", Justification = "objc_getClass method requires CharSet.Ansi to work.")]
        public static extern IntPtr objc_getClass(string name);

        [DllImport(FoundationFramework, EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
        public static extern IntPtr objc_msgSend_retIntPtr(IntPtr target, IntPtr selector);

        [DllImport(AppKitFramework)]
        public static extern IntPtr NSSelectorFromString(IntPtr cfstr);

        [DllImport(FoundationFramework)]
        public static extern void CFRelease(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport(FoundationFramework)]
        public static extern IntPtr CFStringCreateWithBytes(IntPtr allocator, IntPtr buffer, long bufferLength, CFStringEncoding encoding, bool isExternalRepresentation);

        [DllImport(FoundationFramework)]
        public static extern unsafe void CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterRef center, IntPtr observer,
                                   CFNotificationCallback callback, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj,
                                   CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior suspensionBehavior);
    }

    public static void Initialise()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Init Mac power mode test.");

        // Get the appropriate notification centre for system notifications.
        var nsWorkspace = NativeMethods.objc_getClass("NSWorkspace");
        var sharedWorkspace = NativeMethods.objc_msgSend_retIntPtr(nsWorkspace, GetSelector("sharedWorkspace"));
        var notificationCenter = NativeMethods.objc_msgSend_retIntPtr(sharedWorkspace, GetSelector("notificationCenter"));

        // Create the names of the notifications that we will be listening for.
        var nsWorkspaceWillSleepNotification = CreateCFString("NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification");
        var nsWorkspaceDidWakeNotification = CreateCFString("NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification");

        // Listen out for when the Mac is about to sleep. (Test by selecting 'sleep' from the Apple Menu.)
        NativeMethods.CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center: notificationCenter,
                                 observer: notificationCenter,
                                 callback: NotificationCallbackDelegate,
                                 name: nsWorkspaceWillSleepNotification,
                                 obj: IntPtr.Zero,
                                 suspensionBehavior: CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.DeliverImmediately);


        // Listen out for when the Mac is awoken. (Test by pressing space bar whilst sleeping, to wake Mac.)
        NativeMethods.CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center: notificationCenter,
                                 observer: notificationCenter,
                                 callback: NotificationCallbackDelegate,
                                 name: nsWorkspaceDidWakeNotification,
                                 obj: IntPtr.Zero,
                                 suspensionBehavior: CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.DeliverImmediately);
    }

    private static IntPtr GetSelector(string name)
    {
        IntPtr cfstrSelector = CreateCFString(name);
        IntPtr selector = NativeMethods.NSSelectorFromString(cfstrSelector);
        NativeMethods.CFRelease(cfstrSelector);
        return selector;
    }

    private static unsafe IntPtr CreateCFString(string aString)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(aString);
        fixed (byte* b = bytes)
        {
            var cfStr = NativeMethods.CFStringCreateWithBytes(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)b, bytes.Length, CFStringEncoding.UTF16, false);
            return cfStr;
        }
    }

    // Delegate definition for a notification center callback.
    private delegate void CFNotificationCallback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, IntPtr observer, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj, IntPtr userInfo);

    private static CFNotificationCallback NotificationCallbackDelegate = NotificationCallback;

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(CFNotificationCallback))]
    private static void NotificationCallback(CFNotificationCenterRef centerPtr, IntPtr observer, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj, IntPtr userInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"NotificationCallback received {name}");
    }
}
}
```

---

There are no errors reported when I call the code, however the callback method never receives a notification for either sleep or wake. I've even tried creating a simple Cocoa app in XCode to see if I can receive the events at all, and that worked fine.

---

Various links that I've researched:

[Apple Documentation Archive: Registering and unregistering for sleep and wake notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1340/_index.html)

[Apple Developer Documentation: CFNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfnotificationcenter?language=objc)

[Xamarin C# Implementation of CFNotificationCenter](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/main/src/CoreFoundation/CFNotificationCenter.cs)

---

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT (11:30 23/09/2020): I've created a static delegate and changed the code above accordingly as per Hans Passant's suggestion in the comments, the code runs but I still do not receive a notification.

---

Comment: It would help if you linked to the blog posts in question for some additional background.

Comment: @IanKemp I've added the most useful now, will try to add a few more in time.

Comment: `callback: NotificationCallback` is the problem.  That invokes syntax sugar, the C#  compiler automagically creates the delegate object to pass to the pinvoke marshaller.  Which creates a little machine code stub so the native code gets a proper unmanaged function pointer.  That stub doesn't live forever, it gets destroyed when the delegate object gets garbage-collected.  No more callback.  Create the object yourself, ensure it stays alive by storing it in a static variable or by calling GCHandle.Alloc()

Comment: Hi @HansPassant thanks for your suggestion, I've changed the code above using your suggestion by creating a static instance of the delegate to point to my callback, I think this is what you meant.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant I've also tried storing the static delegate instance using GCHandle.Alloc() but this did not work either.

Comment: The only other simple explanation is that you are trying this in an app that doesn't resemble a cocoa app at all.  A console mode app for example, that won't work, CFRunLoopRun() is crucial to allow the OS to make callbacks.  Try this in a small Xamarin app for example.

Comment: HI @HansPassant yes this code is part of a .Net Core console application, and just a small part of it. Up until now any required mac-only Native CoreFoundation method calls haven't required notifications, so I guess the 'CFRunLoopRun()' hasn't been necessary. I will investigate how I can integrate this into a .Net Core Console App. Thanks for your help!